# Is there a way to get DI services in a worker class - without passing them in the constructor?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-server-side

This is for a Blazor server app. I have numerous cases where I have worker classes that need DI services. Passing those to the constructor of each means I am passing 3 - 5 services down these chain of calls to be able to pass them to the appropriate constructors.

This is frustrating because it gives all these methods a bunch of additional parameters which turns simple code into calls that are 2 - 3 lines long because of these services. Basically passing all this down multiple levels is yucky.

Is there some way to set these in some session/circuit object entity where the worker class constructors can then read the services from there?

**Update 2:**

The #1 thing I'd like to get in most every class - ILogger! I have a ton of worker classes where I'd like to have trace level logging I can turn on when I want to know what's happening step by step.

**Update 1:**

Here is an example. For my page creating an appointment I have a matching model. This is tied to the razor page, not to the database. (Only showing the key parts, removed all error return code):

```cs
public class CreateAppointmentPageModel : IIncludesAddressModel
{
    public RichTextModel? DescriptionRichText { get; set; }
    public FileUploadModel? Thumbnail { get; set; }
}

public class RichTextModel
{
    private IBlobService BlobService { get; }
    private IDocumentService DocumentService { get; }
    private IHttpClientFactory HttpClientFactory { get; }

    public RichTextModel(
        IBlobService blobService,
        IDocumentService documentService,
        IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        BlobService = blobService;
        DocumentService = documentService;
        HttpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }
    public async Task InitializeEditor(DxRichEdit editor, string? fileName)
    {
        if (fileName == null)
        {
            await editor.NewDocumentAsync();
            return;
        }

        BlobUrl = BlobService.GetBlobUrl(fileName);
        var url = BlobService.GetAccountNamePlus(fileName);

        var httpClient = HttpClientFactory.CreateClient("AzureBlobs");
        using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url))
        {
            await using (var str = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                await editor.LoadDocumentAsync(str, DocumentFormat.OpenXml);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class FileUploadModel
{
    private IBlobService BlobService { get; }
    private IDocumentService DocumentService { get; }

    public string FileImgSrc
    {
        get
        {
            // if we have content, they uploaded a file
            if (UploadedFileContent != null)
            {
                // if UrlIsUploaded is set, then it's not a bitmap and show that.
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UrlIsUploaded))
                    return UrlIsUploaded;
                // it's a bitmap - return as Base64
                return new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(UploadedFileContent))
                    .ConvertToBase64();
            }
            // it's not uploaded so show UrlNoContent.
            // if the file was previously uploaded, this is that previous file or
            // placeholder
            return UrlNoContent;
        }
    }

    public FileUploadModel(IBlobService blobService, IDocumentService docService,
        string urlNoContent, string? urlIsUploaded = null)
    {

        BlobService = blobService;
        DocumentService = docService;
        UrlNoContent = urlNoContent;
        UrlIsUploaded = urlIsUploaded;
        UploadKey = $"Upload_{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()[..6]}";
    }

    public void Initialize(FileContent? fileContent)
    {
        // for a docx/pdf this flips the display to UrlIsUploaded
        if (fileContent != null)
        {
            if (UrlIsUploaded == null)
                UrlNoContent = BlobService.GetBlobUrl(fileContent.Fullname);
            else
                UrlNoContent = UrlIsUploaded;
        }

        FileContent = fileContent;
    }

    public string GetUploadUri(NavigationManager navigator)
    {
        return navigator
            .ToAbsoluteUri($"{GlobalConstants.UrlFileUpload}{UploadKey}")
                .AbsoluteUri;
    }

    public bool OnFileUploaded(FileUploadEventArgs args, ILogger logger)
    {

        if (UploadController.UploadedFiles.TryRemove(UploadKey, out var data))
        {
            UploadedFileContent = data;
            UploadedFileName = args.FileInfo.Name;
            UploadedFileType = args.FileInfo.Type;
            FileType = FileContent
                .FileInfoToType(UploadedFileType, UploadedFileName);
            return true;
        }

        Trap.Break();
        logger.LogError(
            "Unable to get uploaded file {filename} using key {key}",
            args.FileInfo.Name, UploadKey);
        return false;
    }
}
```

There's two major things going on here. The class `RichTextModel` is for a component on the page that uses the DxRichEdit control that has a mini rich text editor. It provides a `byte[]` that is a DOCX file.

To initialize that control, which may be a new document, but may be editing an existing document, I need the `IDocumentService` and `IHttpClientFactory`. These are needed to directly initialize the control in the razor page.

The second major thing is `FileUploadModel` which is used in conjunction with the DxUpload control for uploading a bitmap (avatar, thumbnail, etc.) In this I need the `IBlobService` to get the existing bitmap for the case of update.

Based on the reactions in the comments (which I respect greatly) you all have me looking for how to avoid this. I think I can remove the need for services around `FileUploadModel` by splitting it in two, the non services part for the parent `CreateAppointmentPageModel` and then a second class, that I create in the page.razor.cs file that takes that and initializes it up front and then saves it off at the end.

In this case this second worker class will need the services passed to its constructor. But that will be a class created in the page.razor.cs and therefore it's a direct pass, not passing through several layers down.

The bigger problem is I don't see how to get around passing those services to `RichTextModel`. Because those are needed when the component is initializing on the page.

Does this help???

Comment: "passing 3 - 5 services down these chain of calls" means you are doing something wrong. All service classes should be resolved through DI, you have too much `new` .

Comment: Please make your question concrete by showing some code examples that demonstrate what you are doing.

Comment: Your worker classes should be services.   If it's not a data class, Component, or static utility class, it almost certainly belongs in DI.  David - please show an example work class.

Comment: @HH, Steven, MrC - I added a lot of detail. In writing that, I see how I can reduce the issue. But not eliminate it. And I have worker classes where the methods in them need to go somewhere, to be used on numerous pages. So I think fundamentally that requires a worker class passed these services. Or am I missing something? TIA a lot - when you all are telling me I'm taking the wrong approach, I respect that and so I'm trying to figure out a solution.

Comment: [InjectAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.injectattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0) can be used in the Blazor components. [Request a service in a component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0#request-a-service-in-a-component)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov These aren't razor or other injectable classes. They're classes I instantiate in my injectable classes.

Comment: You shouldn't  "pass" services down but `[Inject]` them.  DI operates on a tree: when  a class is injectable or depends on injections then your code shouldn't `new()`  it.

Comment: Hint: we don't need to see all those methods here, just the couplings between classes. And that leaves me wondering if your 'Models' are Models or Services. They look stateless but what is `FileContent` ?

Comment: @DavidThielen this class is trying to do the job of 3 others - a UI component, a service and *maybe*, an actual model. That's simply wrong, and the cause of all this confusion. No model or service needs to know about a *specific* UI element like `DxRichEdit` - that's the job of data binding in components. If you split this catch-all class into components, services and DTOs/Models, you'll see that the need for DI is reduced a *lot*. if you extract your service code into an actual service, you won't have to inject IHttpClientFactory into your component

Comment: Are you trying to treat Blazor Server the same way you would a Razor Pages app? Blazor is essentially React#, not Razor Pages vNext. The component model is similar to React's, even in Blazor Server. The primary concept are the components, not their DTOs.  You have nested components and parameter bindings. Data flows from the top down using binding. Operations from the bottom up, using events and callbacks.  Using storage services or calls is the job of the page or top component, not the inner component's.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think you're right. I put too much functionality in two classes that need to be a pure DTO. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are doing this right, but that's a personal opinion.

As you have found, passing multiple services into a non DI class is pretty clumsy.

One solution is to pass only the DI service provider in the constructor.  This is `IServiceProvider`.

Once you have that you can:

1. Use the various versions of the `GetService` method to get the service instance you require from the provider.  All the normal rules apply for injected services.  This method gives you a lot more flexibility in getting different services based on logic.
2. Instantiate non DI classes in the context of the DI container.  They don't need to be a registered services.  You use the static `ActivatorUtilities` class.  The `CreateInstance<MyClass>(IServiceProvider)` method will instantiate an instance of `MyClass` using the services from `IServiceProvider`.

`CreateInstance` looks like this:

```cs
public static T CreateInstance<T> (IServiceProvider provider, params object[] parameters);
```

You even have `parameters` to privide constructor arguments that aren't provided by provider.

In your code:

```cs
    public RichTextModel(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
       _serviceProvider = provider;
        BlobService = provider.GetInstance<IBlobService>();
        //....
        //.. Check for nulls if necessary
    }
```

Comment: I'm redesigning these models as I figure guidance from you & HH is a strong vote that my present design is wrong. With that said, this is a useful trick to remember. Thanks

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos's comments are pretty close to what I would say.  Separate Data from State from Logic from UI.  SRP is the most important SOLID principle by a long way.  Clean Design helps you think logically about how to structure your application and make it testable.